# $C'(1/6)$ groups' properties

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I need to prove the following properties of $C'(1/6)$ groups:

1. If $h^k$ equals relation, then $k$ is an order of $h$
2. All finite subgroups are cyclic
3. All abelian subgroups are cyclic

I guess I've proved 1) with Greendlinger's lemma, but I have no idea how to solve 2) - 3)

I'm solving some problems of a combinatorial group theory course, but I can't solve 2-3. I don't see any instruments except definition, Dehn's algorithm and Greendlinger's lemma. In the second, for example, I'm trying to explore structure of finite cyclic subgroup by applying Dehn's algorithm to generator and comparing it to relations using Greendlinger's lemma. It turns out (if I'm right) that square of generator must be a subword of some relation. But I don't see how that helps...

I would like to have a hint.

Comment: Why do you need to prove these?

Comment: I'm trying to solve problems of a combinatorial group theory course.

Comment: Since you have had no response, you could try asking this on MathOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try.

Comment: (3) should follow from the solution to the conjugacy problem, as you want to prove that any annular diagram with the same internal and external boundary has $0$ area. The solution to the conjugacy problem is like Greendlinger's Lemma but for annular diagrams, and is similarly strong and descriptive. (I don't have the theorem with me just now though, but maybe it's in your notes?)